# How to install F# and use it from aspx page

Tags: asp.net, f#

I am looking for simple answer about installation but without `.msi` and Visual Studio.

I don't use VS, I put dll files inside bin folder, write something to `web.config` and put import in a page.

But for F#, I can't find anything about it, if I find it, its useless for last version of F#.

Same goes for IronPython, and many others :)

If anyone is using asp.net in this "strange" "not normal" way like me, maybe can help

Thank you

Comment: Search for IronPython Tools for Visual Studio, and you'll find the ASP.NET support. IronPython in Action also covers use of IPy with WebForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PowerPack includes a CodeDom provider, but generally speaking, you will be unsuccessful using F# directly to create a WebForms application. You can create your code behind files in a separate F# library and reference those types in your C# WebForms pages. Dan Mohl has several such templates available on nuget.org. Despite much pleading from the F# community, this is the current best approach.

If you want more F#-like approaches, check out [figment](HTTP://github.com/mausch/figment), [WebSharper](HTTP://websharper.com/), and [frank](HTTP://github.com/frank-fs/frank).

Comment: finally some normal answer :), i dont use webforms.. however

Answer (score -4):

You cannot use F# in aspx.

ASP.Net only allows three languages `C#` or `VB` or `J#`

For more information please read: -

[Programming Languages in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbdt8kk7%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: [Plenty](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-mvc-web.aspx) [of samples](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/05/12/f-in-asp-net-mathematics-and-testing.aspx) that you **CAN** use F# in ASP.NET - at least in ASP.NET MVC ... and with a [little hand-made customizing](http://tomasp.net/articles/aspnet-fsharp-intro.aspx), you can use F# in ASP.NET webforms, too.

Comment: Who is deleting my comments about "using JScript.Net" ? .. this looks like "You cannot use F# in aspx" is relevant statement and its not

Comment: @marc_s if you look at Tomas' updated MVC article, you'll notice that the actual web project is a C# project. The F# project provides the implementations.

Comment: ASP.NET allows every language with CodeDOM.